# Having a method re-defining another class's method

Tags: ruby

I have a simple class with a simple method definition

```
class Printer
  def print
    p '1'
  end
end
```

And now I introduce a separate script that re-defines the print method by adding some extra stuff to print

```
class Printer

  alias :old_print :print
  def print
    old_print
    p '2'
  end
end
```

Can I do this programmatically?

```
module Test

  def self.redefine_print(arg)
    # redefine Printer's print method so that it will print all of the stuff it should
    # print, followed by the arg I specified
  end
end
```

So a sample interaction might look like

```
>>>a = Printer.new
>>>a.print
1
>>>Test.redefine_print("new stuff")
>>>a.print
1
new stuff
>>>Test.redefine_print("more")
>>>a.print
1
new stuff
more
```

It is ok if existing instances are affected by the changes (because any instance of Printer will be created, do its printing, and then disposed immediately)

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to want to redefine the method? Why not have a method on `Printer` to add more stuff to be printed?

Comment: You *are* doing it programatically. There's no reason you can't do the same thing outside of the class definition. That said... what's the purpose? If all you're doing is adding on headers/footers/etc. you don't need metaprogramming for that.

Comment: The example I used is pretty over-simplified and was purely for seeing whether something like that was possible or not (method re-defining another method in another class). My solution will probably be something along the lines of what @RenatoZannon mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `define_method` or a module for that, but it is overkill (and probably very slow). It is possible (and simpler) to use a class variables and a class method instead:

```
class Printer
  @@tokens = []

  def print
    @@tokens.each do |token|
      p token
    end
  end

  def self.add_token(token)
    @@tokens << token
  end
end

Printer.add_token("foo")

printer = Printer.new
printer.print
# foo

Printer.add_token("bar")
printer.print
#foo
#bar
```

---

To answer to your question though, it's possible to redefine methods of other classes by using `class_eval` and `define_method`:

```
class Printer
  def print
    p '1'
  end
end

module Test
  def self.redefine_print(arg)
    old_print = Printer.instance_method(:print)
    Printer.class_eval do
      define_method(:print) do
        old_print.bind(self).call
        p arg
      end
    end
  end
end

printer = Printer.new
printer.print
# 1

Test.redefine_print("new stuff")
printer.print
# 1
# new stuff

Test.redefine_print("more")
printer.print
# 1
# new stuff
# more
```

Comment: Why would `define_method` be slow? Once the method is defined, it differs in no way from a method defined directly in the source code. I agree though, that you first approach is a better fit in this situation, but not generally.

Comment: Not exactly. `define_method` involves a closure, with takes up memory. On the example, all the previous definitions of the method need to remain referenced. Also, it invalidates method caches.

Comment: I agree with you on this specific example. Nevertheless `define_method` is great in many cases, but must be carefully used. Another note on your code: You should really use class instance variables instead of class variables, because class variables will easily break encapsulation. See http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ClassInstanceVariable.html for an example

Comment: Yeah, class variables have multiple gotchas ;) I've used one here merely for convenience, but I agree that it's best to stay away from them overall